# can't find dll files in opencv visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv

i'm using visual studio 2012 and running opencv2.4.9

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>

cv::CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
cv::CascadeClassifier eye_cascade;

/**
* Function to detect human face and the eyes from an image.
*
* @param  im    The source image
* @param  tpl   Will be filled with the eye template, if detection success.
* @param  rect  Will be filled with the bounding box of the eye
* @return zero=failed, nonzero=success
*/
int detectEye(cv::Mat& im, cv::Mat& tpl, cv::Rect& rect)  
{
std::vector<cv::Rect> faces, eyes;
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(im, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,       
cv::Size(30,30));
for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
cv::Mat face = im(faces[i]);
eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(face, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE,   
cv::Size(20,20));
if (eyes.size())
{
rect = eyes[0] + cv::Point(faces[i].x, faces[i].y);
tpl  = im(rect);
}
}

return eyes.size();
}

/**
* Perform template matching to search the user's eye in the given image.
*
* @param   im    The source image
* @param   tpl   The eye template
* @param   rect  The eye bounding box, will be updated with the new location                                                      
of the eye
*/
void trackEye(cv::Mat& im, cv::Mat& tpl, cv::Rect& rect)
{
cv::Size size(rect.width * 2, rect.height * 2);
cv::Rect window(rect + size - cv::Point(size.width/2, size.height/2));

window &= cv::Rect(0, 0, im.cols, im.rows);

cv::Mat dst(window.width - tpl.rows + 1, window.height - tpl.cols + 1, 
CV_32FC1);
cv::matchTemplate(im(window), tpl, dst, CV_TM_SQDIFF_NORMED);

double minval, maxval;
cv::Point minloc, maxloc;
cv::minMaxLoc(dst, &minval, &maxval, &minloc, &maxloc);

if (minval <= 0.2)
{
    rect.x = window.x + minloc.x;
    rect.y = window.y + minloc.y;
}
else
    rect.x = rect.y = rect.width = rect.height = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
// Load the cascade classifiers

face_cascade.load("C:/ashish2/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2    .xml");
eye_cascade.load("C:/ashish2/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml");

// Open webcam
cv::VideoCapture cap(0);

// Check if everything is ok
if (face_cascade.empty() || eye_cascade.empty() || !cap.isOpened())
    return 1;

// Set video to 320x240
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320);
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);

cv::Mat frame, eye_tpl;
cv::Rect eye_bb;

while (cv::waitKey(15) != 'q')
{
cap >> frame;
if (frame.empty())
break;

// Flip the frame horizontally, Windows users might need this
cv::flip(frame, frame, 1);

// Convert to grayscale and 
// adjust the image contrast using histogram equalization
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

if (eye_bb.width == 0 && eye_bb.height == 0)
{
// Detection stage
// Try to detect the face and the eye of the user
detectEye(gray, eye_tpl, eye_bb);
}
else
{
// Tracking stage with template matching
trackEye(gray, eye_tpl, eye_bb);

// Draw bounding rectangle for the eye
cv::rectangle(frame, eye_bb, CV_RGB(0,255,0));
}

// Display video
cv::imshow("video", frame);
}

return 0;
}
```

when i run below code it gives me 'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Orayan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test2\Debug\test2.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Orayan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test2\Debug\opencv_core249.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Orayan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test2\Debug\opencv_highgui249.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvfw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avifil32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\avicap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Orayan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test2\Debug\opencv_imgproc249.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Orayan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\test2\Debug\opencv_objdetect249.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devenum.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msdmo.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qcap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\quartz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksproxy.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ksuser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d9.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d8thk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vidcap.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Kswdmcap.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mfc42.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcint.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0x1564 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\qedit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.7600.16385_none_72fc7cbf861225ca\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumdx32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3dim700.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumd32.dll'
'test2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
'test2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumdx32.dll'
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumdx32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumd32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumd32.dll'
'test2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
'test2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\igdumdx32.dll'
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xmp4_dshow.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'test2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msyuv.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x9cc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'test2.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msyuv.dll'
The thread 0x166c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x4b0 has exited with code 1 (0x1).
The program '[5944] test2.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
:

even i have manually copied the opencv_highgui249.dll,opencv_core249.dll.and also in the properties of this file i have provided all the path coorectly.

Comment: What isn't working, exactly? The only error I see in that wall of output text is that one of the threads is exiting with a non-zero return code...

Comment: you're reading the output wrong. the pdb warnings do not matter, see, in the end it says: " The program '[5944] test2.exe' has exited with code 1 "  and you want to know why ? look at your code :  `// Check if everything is ok
if (face_cascade.empty() || eye_cascade.empty() || !cap.isOpened())
    return 1;` - so, one of your cascade files was not found. simply.

Comment: i have given the path for xml files correctly : face_cascade.load("C:/ashish2/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2    .xml");
eye_cascade.load("C:/ashish2/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_eye.xml");    ---------even though it don't detect these files .